# how can I automatically invoke the controller action on starting of IIS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

There's a requirement of calling an `action` or a `constructor` of my [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) `MVC5 Web Api` Application whenever I start/restart `IIS8` server.
Can it be done (without browsing the site)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the auto start feature of IIS 7.5+: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/05/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/